# After you JSENDCODE text, how do I keep the proper format of an apostrophe?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, docusignapi

I'm attempting to pre-populate data into a visualforce page utilizing a custom button. In my use case, this is DocuSign custom button logic.

I will be providing Salesforce merge fields as well as text strings.

I've successfully coded URLENCODE in addition with JSENCODE so i do not receive any syntax errors from merged data. However, in my fields and text strings with apostrophe's, it adds a backslash in front **\'**.

Below is an example of one of my variables:

```
CES="{!URLENCODE(JSENCODE(Account.Name))} {!URLENCODE(JSENCODE(Opportunity.Name))} - eSignature";
```

My Account Name in Salesforce = "Dunder Mifflin's".

In the visualforce page it is displayed as "**Dunder Mifflin\'s**"

Is there any way to ENCODE the apostrophe, but still keep the format the same without the backslash?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use 2 encoding functions? Sounds like one would be enough. If there are two - well yeah, your output will be double-escaped.

Also if that link is being built on Visualforce page then you can build it in more elegant way and let Visualforce engine figure out the escaping for you:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:outputLink value="http://google.com/search">
    Search Google Images
    <apex:param name="q" value="{!account.name}"/>
    <apex:param name="tbm" value="isch"/>
</apex:outputLink>
</apex:page>
```

gives me

`http://google.com/search?q=Dunder%20Miffin%27s&tbm=isch`

Comment: Thanks eyescream. I'm new. Just using URLENCODE worked for me.